# I want to stop a method without completing it's instructions if a certain flag is triggered

Tags: python, tkinter, return

I have a method which displays a Toplevel window every few seconds, anyhow if user clicks on **dismiss** button instead of **ok** button, the remaining toplevel windows should not be displayed. In below code disAction() is the command for dismiss button

I tried using while loop, it shows 'Not responding' error

```
def topRequester(self):
if self.dismiss == 0:
    self.after(SLEEP_SEC, self.toplevelmaker)
    self.after(SLEEP_SEC + SLEEP_SEC, self.toplevelmaker)
    self.after(SLEEP_SEC + SLEEP_SEC*2, self.toplevelmaker)
    self.after(SLEEP_SEC + SLEEP_SEC*2, self.topRequester)

def disAction(self):  # the cycle should be disrupted
    self.topwin.withdraw()
    self.dismiss = 1
```

Comment: if you create many Toplevel windows then you should keep them on list, not in one variable. If you create new Toplevel and assing to the same variable then you don't have access to previous Toplevel.

Comment: create minimal working code with your problem so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: You can save the IDs returned by `after(...)` and use `after_cancel(id)` to cancel the tasks.

Comment: I released that `disAction` is executed long after `topRequester` so it can't skip `after` used in `topRequester`. You would have to keep all `id = after(...)` in `topRequester` and use them in `disAction` in `after_cancel(id)` as said @acw1668. OR you would have to use `if self.dismiss == 0:` inside `toplevelmaker` which is executed later then `disAction`.

Comment: Please provide a testable example. Just looking at what you have now I am not sure you are using after in the correct manor. It should be a very simple thing to keep track of a class attribute as a flag and to stop the window creation/opening cycle. You will fined this link helpful for writing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I used after_cancel(id) as suggested by @acw1668 and got rid of `self.dismiss ` this is a working example https://pastebin.com/EkNDndqa

Comment: @Mike-SMT and furas, I'll make sure I post a testable code next time, thank you